# crystal report print error: attempt to read or write protected memory

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

please this error appears when the user clicks on print button , on my PC the error dosen't appear , only on some pc's ! what is the problem ?

before ,this error did not appear,only now !

my code in vb.net
crystal reports for vs2010
report's datasource on local server

edited :
This is my code (report load button) :

```
    Dim mov As New leavingReport
    Dim rep As New rep
    LogOn(mov, DataBasePath, DataBasePath, "Admin", "")
    rep.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = mov
    mov.Refresh()
    rep.ShowDialog()
    mov.Dispose()
    rep.Dispose()
```

Thank You

Comment: Before what?  What changed that before the change the error did not occur?  How are they running the report?  Can they see the report, just not print it?

Comment: sorry,there is no any change , just this error now appears, and before dosen't appear (before mean before a few days), yes , they can do all things : show,export,zoom but print .